# Are these metric spaces complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Are the following metric spaces complete?

**(1)** $(X_f, d_f)$, where $X_f=\{0,1,2,3\}$, $d_f(x,y)=|x-y|$

**(2)** $(X_d, d_d)$, where $X_d=\mathbb{N}$, $d_d(x,y)=|x-y|$

Since these spaces do not seem to have any Cauchy sequences, does this mean they are vacuously complete? Alternatively, these metric spaces only have open sets, so we can't verify their completeness topologically either.

Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Isn't every eventually constant sequence Cauchy?

Comment: Do you know what are the Cauchy sequences of those spaces?

Comment: You're right. I remembered about constant sequences in $\mathbb{N}$ yesterday, but today I was for some reason only thinking in terms of non-constant sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only cauchy sequences in those spaces are the constant sequences (because $|x-y| \geq 1$ if $x \neq y$). Therefore they are trivially convergent and your spaces are complete

Comment: So are these spaces vacuously complete in terms of topology? That is, since there are no open subsets in these spaces, there are no non-empty intersections of closed sets.

Comment: Those sets have open subset e.g. the ball of radius 2 centred in 0, which is the set $\{ 0,1\} $. The fact is that to ask for a chain of decrasing closed subset with diameter tending to zero is to ask for a chain of decreasing closed subset which eventually stabilises at a one point set.